# valarray complexity

Tags: c++, stl, complexity-theory

What are the time complexities for the `valarray::min` and `valarray::max` functions in STL?

Also, what would be a good source for finding about the time/space complexities of various other STL components?

Comment: How could they be anything other than `O(N)`?

Comment: When called for the first time, yes, they shall take `O(N)` time. But maybe it is possible to store it in a field so the future calls can just get the stored value instead of going over it once more?

Comment: it is possible (if you keep tracking the changing values of the array) -- but it's NOT specified. I.e., you might (although I doubt it) a different implementation, but the standard specifies O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(N)

these functions do not cache their results.

Search for section titled "Complexity" in any stl reference, e.g.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/

or

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/min_element.html
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/max_element.html

Time complexity specification is part of STL specification for almost every method and function.

Memory complexities are normally not specified..

There is good reason for these [low-level] functions not caching min/max results:
if you want to quickly get min/max element of a container that is modified often, you can
(1)  cahe/maintain min/max values yourself
(2) use heap or trees instead of vector

Answer (score 0):

A good place to check the complexity of STL components: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/